# Slow wordpress website despite being fully optimised

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, host

I really need your help. I build a website with WordPress and it’s finished. I optimized my website and speed on google is 99% for mobile and pc. At GTmetrix the score is also really good 90%. Sometimes my website is repsonding really slow. I sometimes have a load time of 20 – 30 seconds for a product page. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? I already tried everything. The host I am using is good. The server is doing nothing so there is a lot of speed left. Below you’ll find some pictures of the problem and the optimilisation of my website. I really need your help! I would be very grateful, a reward for those who find the problem. By the way I am using WP rocket with redis cache and sometimes the Ajax loading time does take a long time to load.

Comment: Provide link. The images you speak of are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Server side, I would verify the web server is correctly configured.  For example take a look at the Apache and MySQL logs at the time of your issue.

Client side, I would take a look at what's taking so long to be loaded.  Maybe using browser web dev tools.

Network side, does it only happen to you?  Can you make it happen from another IP?

Is the issue reproducible?  For example if you stress test the server with AB or similar, what happens?